# Confirm() Doesn't decline when I press decline

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

When I Press the delete button I will show a confirm()
So when I press Accept it will delete the row out of the db but when I press cancel it will also delete it out of the db.

```html
<a href="template_edit.php?delete=<?=$vragen['formBuildingBlockId']?>&templateId=<?=$_GET['templateId']?>"
   onclick="if(confirm('Weet u zeker dat u deze checklist wilt weggooien?') 
   window.location='functions.php?delete=<?=$checklist['formInstanceId']?>&amp;type=checklist';">
   <img src="<?=IMG?>/delete.png" title="Verwijderen" alt="Checklist verwijderen" />
</a>
```

I hope you guys know what the problem is and may help me :)

Greets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a bracket. And since you are doing something using `JavaScript` instead of following the link's `href`, why have you kept a URL in it?
There were a few other minor syntactical errors which have been corrected as well.

Try:

```html
<a href="#"
   onclick="if(confirm('Weet u zeker dat u deze checklist wilt weggooien?')) window.location='functions.php?delete=<?=$checklist['formInstanceId'];?>&type=checklist';">
   <img src="<?=IMG;?>/delete.png" title="Verwijderen" alt="Checklist verwijderen" />
</a>
```

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="template_edit.php?delete=<?=$vragen['formBuildingBlockId']?>&templateId=<?=$_GET['templateId']?>"
   onclick="if(!confirm('Weet u zeker dat u deze checklist wilt weggooien?'){
   window.location='functions.php?delete=<?=$checklist['formInstanceId']?>&amp;type=checklist'; return false;}">
   <img src="<?=IMG?>/delete.png" title="Verwijderen" alt="Checklist verwijderen" />
</a>
```

Basically, you have to add `return false` to not follow the link.